# Control Apple Watch's Brightness programmatically

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

Is there any way to control Apple Watch's Brightness programmatically?

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, But I found the explanation that apple does not gives that privilege to programmer as it will directly effect the battery consumption. Even my app got rejected because it was using screen light.

Comment: By any chance, is it possible now? @BitKnight Can you share the link please

Comment: I am not aware.